# запуск php скрипта по кнопке

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Есть php скрипт в папке, update.php. Он запускается автоматом через cron, и чтобы не лез никто лишний, доступ к нему запрещен htaccess.
А хочется иногда запустить скрипт вручную,через админ-панель, например через кнопку. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Самый тупой, но рабочий способ - запускать .sh или .bat при клике, а в нём curl на твой скрипт php :D

Answer (score 2):

В файле `admin.php`:

```
<?php

echo '<a href="/admin.php?execute=update">Execute update</a>';

if(array_key_exists('execute',$_GET)){
    echo 'Start...';
    include 'update.php';
    echo 'Done.';
}
```

Comment: там же доступ закрыт для пользователей

Comment: @Dmitriy, это web-серверу закрыт, но не php же

Comment: Прикольная идея)))

Answer (score 1):

Создать еще скрипт, который будет выполняться при нажатии кнопки и в нем

```
   exec('php update.php');
```

и лучше указать полный путь до php и update.php, что-то вроде

```
   exec('/usr/bin/php /var/www/site/update.php');
```