# запуск долгого php скрипта в shell по кнопке на сайте

Tags: php, redis

Есть php скрипт, который запускается автоматом через cron как в [запуск php скрипта по кнопке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700161/) но данный там совет запускать через `exec('/usr/bin/php /var/www/site/update.php');` (у меня есть еще параметры `exec('/usr/bin/php /var/www/site/update.php full');`) не помогает, поскольку если запустить в консоли, скрипт работает около 20 мин и выводит очень много сообщений отчитываясь о выполнении каждую секунду (это изменить нельзя). за это время страница успевает недогрузися и написать ошибку `504 Gateway Time-out`. увеличивать время выполнения нельзя, поэтому предполагаю что curl и wget так же не поможет. пробовал сразу в код страницы, вызываемый при нажатии кнопки вставить весь скрипт вместо вызова его через exec, добавил перед выполнением скрипта `ignore_user_abort(true)`. страница некоторое время как бы грузится, потом показывается начальная часть положенного при выполнении за это время вывода и на этом все прекращается. есть ли еще варианты? На английской части форума дан совет использовать Redis но в его описании я не нашел как он может запускать внешние скрипты. В итоге сделал как написано в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953. страница так же отваливается но результат получается. как временное решение пойдет. буду рад если кто-то предложит вариант лучше и может проще.

Comment: Что делает ваш скрипт и что это за "страница которая успевает недогрузится и написать ошибку " ?
Что по вашему есть Redisи почему он должен запускать скрипты ?

Comment: Скрипт берет данные из базы и преобразует их загружает в таблицы и обновляет кэш. Его менять нельзя. Страница на которой я ставлю вызов `exec` показывает все сообщения, которые показывает скрипт когда его запускаю в консоли. Но поскольку он это делает очень долго, то страница остается незагруженной до конца и работа скрипта прекращается, несмотря на все данные советы. Воспользоваться Редис предложили в https://stackoverflow.com/a/51969016/10017438. Я не понял как, хотя он требовал отметить совет как ответ. Мне не важно как сделать, главное результат.

Comment: Код скрипта пробовал полностью разместить в контроллере, но ситуация та же. Увеличивать время выполнения в настройках пхп нельзя. Получается наиболее вероятное решение через ключевой файл и еще одно задание крона, которое будет запускать нужный скрипт при появлении файла, но хочется обойтись без этого. Идея с Редис понравилась тем, что он есть. Но как это сделать я не нашел, а давший совет не сообщает. С таким же успехом можно написать что блокнотом можно сделать без реального примера. Но решение реальное когда известно как это сделать и будет практически реализовано.

Comment: Давайте поймем что Redis - это чтоб совсем по-простому инструмент хранения данных в памяти, который позволяет очень быстро записывать туда и очень быстро получать оттуда. Никакого отношения к запуску чего либо он не имеет.

Comment: Я это знаю, поэтому удивлен такому совету, но как Вы наверное читали - это было. Пусть без него главное просто и эффективно. Если прописать вначале команды screen то его надо еще как-то глушить по окончании.

Comment: По поводу вашей задачи. Отвечающих вам правильно указывает на то, что вам нужно воспользоваться "очередями". В частности RabbitMQ, например. Работает это так - вы запускаете свой скрипт, который посылает сообщение в некую очередь. С другой стороны есть скрипты, которые слушают очередь (висят в памяти) получают оттуда сообщения и выполняют нужную работу, записывая свой результат как либо или куда либо.  Ну и просмотр результата вы делаете либо через логи либо через созданный веб интерфейс.

Comment: Ну и если вы хотите можете через крон выполнять, а результаты писать в файл. В любом случае нет смысла запускать скрипт через веб и ждать.

Comment: сейчас он через крон и запускается каждый час. но бывает необходимость сделать это внепланово. городить добавляя еще сервисов не хочется. задача внепланово запустить сам скрипт или задачу крона. а результат читать вообще нет необходимости.

Comment: ну если не хочется "городить сервисов", тогда обходитесь тем что есть.

Comment: так в том и вопрос что ничего нет. сейчас только крон запускает. неужели чтобы почистить килограмм картошки надо целый комбайн покупать? больше всего запущено значит больше мест возможной поломки. неужели только раньше учили минимализму? неужели нет того кто поможет решить эту задачу? сейчас видится наиболее реальным писать лок файл и другим скриптом его ожидать. но ведь тоже не правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в конечном итоге на пхп сделал скрипт, который создает файл-флаг  в определенном месте. крон периодически запускает другой скрипт, который проверяет наличие этого флага. и при наличии, запускает нужный долгий скрипт. а после окончания удаляет флаг. чтобы не делать много условий и рисковать тем что где-то не сработает, было сделано по такой цепочке на каждую нужную долгую команду. тем самым нет риска что увеличенным временем выполнения пхп скрипта воспользуется злоумышленник.